# how to draw svg path animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, css-animations

i have 3 glowing blub and 2 dotted line joining them.i have to pass a light glow(like every dash is glowing one by one) through the lines from one to other blub in a repeating manner.So far i am able to achieve this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/hsfxS/3856/..

```
<div class="mr-glow-1">
              <svg width="401" height="332" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <line stroke-dasharray="10, 5" x1="0" y1="1" x2="600" y2="600" style="stroke-width: 2px; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></line>
              </svg>
            </div>
```

The dotted line actually comes from a background image. i just have to pass a pink light glow through the dotted lines showing that transition is happening from one to other.How do i achieve this?I am working in angular 4 but can do the animation by pure javascript.

Comment: new fiddle link  https://jsfiddle.net/hsfxS/3857/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<animate>` elements to animate a change of X and Y position

https://codepen.io/danjiro/post/how-to-make-svg-loop-animation

```
<animate attributeName="cx" from="50" to="250"
    dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

So you can make a glowing circle and animate its changing x and y position with the animate element

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do what you want. It all depends on how you want the effect to look and how fancy you want to get.

For instance, here is one way. It animates `stroke-dashoffset` to moves a small dash along a second line so that it appears to follow the first line.

```html
<svg width="401" height="332" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line stroke-dasharray="10, 5" x1="0" y1="1" x2="600" y2="600" style="stroke-width: 2px; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>
  <line stroke-dasharray="14, 1000" x1="0" y1="1" x2="600" y2="600" style="stroke-width: 8px; stroke: rgba(192, 64, 64, 0.5);">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="-848" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </line>
</svg>
```